# How to configure Facebook + Oauth module in drupal 7

Tags: facebook, drupal, oauth

I am looking for a way to configure Facebook + Oauth module in Drupal 7, as i am working to allow users to log-in into my site using their Facebook user/pass and at the same time i would like to save their Facebook details in my Database. I have been looking for a tutorial or a step by step process to configure these modules.

Please help me. Once i manage to do this, i am going to create article explaining this process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the module http://drupal.org/project/fb

> This set of modules turns Drupal into a platform for developing
>   Facebook Applications. This allows you to embed your content and
>   features within facebook, or allow facebook users onto your site via
>   Facebook Connect.
>
> With Drupal for Facebook, you can harness all the power of Drupal in
>   you Facebook App. If you already have content in Drupal, you can
>   expose it on Facebook.

Hope this module will full fill all your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've made several sites with that kind of functionality, and I always end up using the Facebook Oauth module instead of Drupal for Facebook:
http://drupal.org/project/fboauth

The FB OAuth module allows you to integrate Facebook login so much more quickly and easily than Drupal for Facebook. Also, you can map users' fields to Facebook data sources - which probably fits your intended use of their Facebook details.